# Unity boolean not showing up in inspector view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm on macOS High Sierra (10.13.3), Unity version 2019.2.17f1 Personal.

When I initialize a boolean, it's supposed to show up in the inspector view of the script. This is not happening. I've tried restarting Unity to no avail. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Strange. Did you try to add the `[Serializable]` attribute on the bool? Maybe it solves it.

Comment: If it's public it is serialized anyway .. is there a custom Inspector for this class? In general don't post pictures of code .. post the code!

Comment: Do you get any error in the Console?

Comment: Oh btw you are in the reference settings .. these make sense with references .. is your book showing up in the Inspector if you attach that script to a GameObject?

Comment: @derHugo Thank you!! That solved the problem - the script by itself has no toggle (obviously), but when I click on the Clock game object it's attached to, the checkbox appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said the settings you are showing us here are the script import settings where you can configure some default **references**. So here only reference typed fields will be visible.

Your `bool` field should be serialized as soon as you go to the Inspector of an instance of your script attached to a GameObject or prefab.